# CAD *.stp files on Ubuntu 13.04 32Bit

Tags: 3d, cad

I'm not able to open 3D CAD *.stp files on my Ubuntu, I tried to import them with Salome Meca however without effect ? What went wrong ?

Answer (score 8):

To open .stp files, try FreeCAD.

> FreeCAD is an Open Source CAx RAD based on OpenCasCade, Qt and Python.
>   It features some key concepts like macro recording, workbenches,
>   ability to run as a server and dynamically loadable application
>   extensions and it is designed to be platform independent.
>
> Currently, FreeCAD can import and display CAD models in IGES, STEP,
>   and BRep formats and meshes in STL, BMS, AST and Wavefront OBJ
>   formats. Editing and modeling features are currently somewhat limited.

For more info check out their [Website](http://www.freecadweb.org/).

To install click [**FreeCAD** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/freecad/)

<sup>Source:Ubuntu Apps</sup>